# Why is occur "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch"?

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-urls

My goal is to implement `google authentication` in my `Django website`. But it shows,

```
Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

***Why did it occur?*** I tried to implement it in the local host. Give me an understandable solution so that as a beginner I can understand. The same Kinda issues occur for the `facebook authentication` too.

***google developer console:***

*Authorized JavaScript origins:*

```
urls1:http://localhost:8000
urls2:http://127.0.0.1:8000
urls3:http://localhost:3000
urls4:http://localhost
```

*Authorized redirect URIs:*

```
urls1:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
urls2:http://localhost:8000
urls3:http://localhost:3000
urls4:http://localhost
```

***settings.py:***

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]
```

context_processors:

```
'social_django.context_processors.backends',
'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
        'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    ]



LOGIN_URL = '/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/' 
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '****'    #security purpose I hide this
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '****'    #security purpose I hide this
```

***urls.py***

```
path('social-auth/', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social'))
```

***template:***

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add these to your google console's Authorized redirect URIs:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
 
 http://localhost:8000/auth/google_oauth2/callback
```

Comment: did not work....

Comment: if it doesn't work then you must need to check your client secret and API key and you can also follow this - https://python.plainenglish.io/django-social-authentication-login-with-google-30d82838fa33

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you share the screen shot for the same so I can get it clearly.

Comment: please check the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NJkBRKphYSvrzuZpxbNpJ4rMlX6Pzo6F/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I guess you don't need to mention the javascript origins. And also can you please show me the error screenshot so I can get it clearly?